# Unzip a file to its current directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I've figured out that extracting a `.zip` you need the path to the directory as well when you are recursively looking through subdirectories. So how do you store the path?
This is nearly there but doesn't work properly when there is a space in the `{zip_file}`.

```
zip_dir=$PWD/$(basename "${zip_file}")
```

Comment: I see you've aksed a lot of questions recently - what's the overall aim you are after? :) We may be able to show you an easier method.

Comment: As I was shown before, I am sorry for the backslashes.  I use those in echo lines, so I'm sorry about that.  This line as is works fine.  I agree with Tim, what is the goal here?  There might be a problem with what you are trying to do next with the `zip_dir` variable.

Comment: For my understanding, I am breaking the problem into bits. This script (http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1619154-how-to-unzip-files-recursively) is close to what I want but I don't just want to copy a "magic" script not knowing how it works.
The problem with this script is I don't want a folder called... myfile.zip and I want it to recursively search subfolders.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle okay, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files may help, as may http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107995/how-do-you-recursively-unzip-archives-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-from. Also, when you reply try to remember to include the `@Name` so they are notified!

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle so after your `zip_dir=$PWD/$(basename "${zip_file}")` add another line defining it again as `zip_dir=${zip_dir%.*}` to remove the `.zip` from the name.  It is OK to have multiple lines defining things with the same variable as long as the last one is the one you want.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle then when it makes the directories, make sure you leave the quotes around the variable.  `mkdir -p "$zip_dir"`

Comment: Thanks  @Tim . I've looked at both of those today. The first one I really didn't understand the accepted answer so I looked at the second one which is no good because it doesn't create a folder per zip file.

Comment: I have managed to recursively create a folder for each zip file but can't then unzip them to their own directory.

Comment: @Terrance Adding `zip_dir=${zip_dir%.*}` is the answer to my original question.

Comment: I still have the problem of getting the full path to the folder.
If I could append `zip_file=${filename%.*}` to `$PWD` minus the `./` this would be the correct path.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle I just created a script that I tested, and it worked in my Downloads folder fine.  It created and extracted the files to that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this from your other question as well.  It took me a bit, but this is what I was able to come up with to create the folders based on the zip file name, removing the `.zip` from the folder name, then extracting the zip file into that folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start folder create..."
find . -type f -iname "*.zip" | while read filename
do
 filename1=${filename:2}
 foldername=$PWD/"${filename1%.*}"
 mkdir -p "$foldername"
 unzip "$filename" -d "$foldername"
 echo "Created directory $foldername and extracted files to it." 
done
```

The line `filename1=${filename:2}` strips off the `./` of the name.

Comment: That nearly worked perfectly but one folder had a space so it ignored that when doing the unzip

Comment: My mistake -I forgot the quotes!

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle I also made some simple corrections for deeper folders if existing, but should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I must not have tested this correctly.

Generally you don't need quotes when doing a variable assignment, just when dereferencing a variable.  When making an assignment you don't need to put quotes around a variable being dereferenced, but since the dereferencing happens in a sub shell, quotes are needed around the `${zip_file}` part so that it's value is properly passed to basename.  Quotes are *NOT* in fact needed around the entire line, because then it's back in the context of variable assignment, where quotes aren't needed as bash will do the right thing with passing the value from the subshell to the assignment line.

Thanks @janos for pointing this out.  I'm not sure what I screwed up in testing the original line that took me down the path of excessive quotes.  You are correct, the following is fine:

```
zip_dir=$PWD/$(basename "${zip_file}")
```